# Find discrepancies between 2 nested SQL table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 SQL tables, both have the same schema, a primary key column and a nested column. For example, the first column is `id` and the nested column is `elements`. I want to loop over these tables and find which ids have different number of elements between the 2 tables. How can I do that?

For example:

**Case 1**

[image]

The query should return something like NULL because all IDs have the same number between 2 tables.

**Case 2**

[image]

The query should return `id 1` because `id 1` in table 3 has 3 elements while in table 4 `id 1` only has 2 elements.

Thanks

Comment: A [mcve] would make this clearer. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: @jarlh edited with examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and array_length(t1.elements) != array_length(t2.elements)
```